# Inadmissible value or data type

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Installed this extension. But got an error:

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/20671

> Inadmissible value or data type. Index out of defined range.

At line 250 of OutputHelpers [My Macros & Dialogs].TheCAT

How do I modify the extension so that it will work on windows?

Comment: The extension has no error on Ubuntu. It seems to be windows only bug.

Comment: I was able to run on Windows LibreOffice 7.3.7.2 (x64) just fine.
Extensions are packaged as a "zip" file, which you can open using something like 7-zip. The file you are referencing "OutputHelpers.xba" is located within "TheCat" folder inside the package. Line 250 seem to be a comment, though. I think your best bet is email the developer (in the app's About) and provide the LibreOffice version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the extension programmer.

In fact, I guess that L245 (If Not IsEmpty(l_Desc) Then)
should read:

If Tools.ArrayExists(l_Desc) Then

that is, use a home-made function dedicated to array existence validation.
Could you test and report (to my @, as shown in the App module)?

Comment: It worked after that correction. Adding bounty of 50 points as a token of appreciation!